# If $E[X\mid Y]=0$ a.s., does it follow that $E[X\mid f(Y)]=0$ a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory

If $E[X\mid Y]=0$ a.s., does it follow that $E[X\mid f(Y)]=0$ a.s., for any measurable function $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$ and $\mathcal{G}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f(Y)$.  By definition, if $A\in\mathcal{G}$, then there is a Borel set such that $A=(f\circ Y)^{-1}(B)$. But $(f\circ Y)^{-1}=Y^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$ and so 
$$
A=(f\circ Y)^{-1}(B)=Y^{-1}(f^{-1}(B)).
$$ 
Because of $f$'s measurability, $f^{-1}(B)$ is also Borel-measurable. We infer that $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and, more importantly, $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$. Now the claim follows:
$$
E[X|f(Y)]=E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[E(X|\mathcal{F})|\mathcal{G}]=E[E(X|Y)|\mathcal{G}]=E[0|\mathcal{G}]=0.
$$
The second equality above makes use of iterated conditioning and $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score -1):

If you take $f(x)=x$ then $E[X|f(Y)]=E[X|Y]=0$.

Is this really the problem you wanted to ask?

Comment: So you say that this does not hold for any measurable function?

Comment: Do you wan't your question to ask for every $f$, or for some $f$. Right now you have asked if for some $f$. If for some, then showing one example, as in this answer, is enough.